# IMAPCopy - Bad or invalid system flag \RECENT

Tags: debian, email-server, imap

I'm using [IMAPCopy 1.04](http://www.ardiehl.de/imapcopy/).

During the copy process I get the following errors for many messages:

```
Bad or invalid system flag \RECENT
```

(messages with this error are not copied at all)

What does it mean and how to fix this?

Comment: FWIW, I'm encountering this quite frequently while writing my own imap client. It's not specific to IMAPCopy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your config file:

```
DenyFlags "\Recent"
```

As written here:

https://www.tomwerf.nl/migrate-emails-with-imapcopy-and-ssl/

> You are strongly advised to use DenyFlags  “\Recent”. If the mailbox you are trying to copy has some messages marked by the server “\Recent” this flag can not be carried over (as per RFC). With the denyflag, IMAPcopy will ignore the resent flag. Otherwise, this will result in an error. And the /resent messages will not be copied.